# IE still catches mouse-actions behind fullscreen div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a strange issue with IE (tested on IE8 as this is the lower end browser on the project)

I make a fill height & full width div appear on the screen on some condition to block all user action (it's just a help, I know it can easily been broken user-side..)

The only action that can be done is clicking on this curtain at a certain x/y range to disable it.

But, obviously, in Internet explorer it doesn't work.. elements behind the div are still catching click and hover actions... Why?

My first idea was that there was something wrong with the css making this div a 0x0px div on IE, but when I add a background-color to the div, it fills the screen as expected, so that's not the solution.

this is the curtain's css :

```
#screencurtain {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; display:block; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index:9000;}
```

Comment: "*only action is clicking on it at a certain x/y range*"... it might be helpful to include the code for this click event in your question, as it may be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in IE with positioned elements.

The most common solution is to set the element's `background` property.

If you need the background to remain transparent, you can simply use a transparent image as a background tile. Alternatively, you can set the element's background to an image that does not exist.

For example:

```css
#screencurtain {background:url('transparent.gif') repeat;} /* 10x10 gif image */

/* OR */

#screencurtain {background:url('some-made-up-image.gif');} /* bogous path */
```

Comment: This indeed works, thanks a lot Boaz, used a old vintage 1x1 transparent gif.